# Visual Studio 2017 Project Parameters Bug?

Tags: visual-studio

I had a VS2015 project, opened it in VS2017, and the parameters box is now incredibly small and cannot be resized. The parameters box was regularly-sized for VS2015. I deleted the .csproj.user file but that does not appear to be the fix. Any ideas?

Thanks.

[image: VS2017 Project]

[image: VS2015 Project]

Comment: I see you're running in High-DPI mode. Given the Project Parameter area is displayed with WinForms  I think it's a legacy of poor high-DPI support in WinForms. What does VS2015 look like at the same DPI settings?

Comment: @Dai there is no issue with VS2015, I added a screen shot.